# insert data into table that results from a JOIN SELECT QUERY?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I insert data to a table that results from a JOIN SELECT query

I'd like to insert into b.URL the value ="ok" from the result of the query below

```
SELECT
  a.ESN,
  b.URL,
  a.Status,
  a.GroupID,
  a.RouteID
FROM STx a
  LEFT JOIN Routes b
    ON a.RouteID = b.RouteID
WHERE a.GroupID = 39
    AND a.Status = "Tested"
order by a.ESN;
```

Comment: I suppose you needn't insert but update.

Comment: update isn't doing the job because the whole column is NULL

Comment: To which table you want to insert data from select?

Comment: So, to clarify, you need to put the value `'ok'` on the column `URL` of the `Routes` table, if they match with that `JOIN`?

Comment: I just want to insert data into the routes table

Comment: @user2041213 Ok, that's what I'm trying to clarify. It sounds like you already have rows on the `Routes` table, and you want to `UPDATE` that column following your logic. Is that correct?

Comment: I think I understand what he means. Check my answer please.

Comment: What is the condition to set b.URL to "ok"?

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe this is what you need:

```
UPDATE Routes b 
SET URL = 'ok' 
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM STx a 
     WHERE a.GroupID = 39 
       AND a.Status = 'Tested' 
       AND a.RouteID = b.RouteID)
```

This will set the desired URL values to 'ok'.

Comment: Are you sure you have GroupID = 39 AND Status = 'Tested' in some rows, and also a RouteID from the Routes table?

Comment: Okay, I do some testing, and will come back with the results in 5 minutes (I create sample tables and test this query on them.)

Comment: give the URL column rows NULL values 'cause that's what I have

Comment: It says to me: 2 rows affected. ( Query took 0.0033 sec ). So it works here. I don't know what could be the problem. Could you give me an export of the table data so I can try it on that?

Comment: Antoher possibility is that you run the query twice. MySQL will say that 0 rows affected if you SET the fields to the same value they have now. So if they already have 'ok', then it'll say no rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

You just prefix it with `INSERT INTO table (columns)`. If you are trying to find `b.URL` values in your `SELECT`, then add a filter.

Comment: dont understand what you mean

Comment: This isn't going to go well.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into desire_table (col1,col2,col3,...) SELECT
  a.ESN,
  b.URL,
  a.Status,
  a.GroupID,
  a.RouteID
FROM STx a
  LEFT JOIN Routes b
    ON a.RouteID = b.RouteID
WHERE a.GroupID = 39
AND a.Status = "Tested"
order by a.ESN;
```

Remember that the output columns has to be matched in order to be able to sit in the new table, orders mather it means your first selected column goes to col1 and second one goes to col2 so you have to match the col1,col2,and so on with your select output